# Debreu's Representation Theorem proof

Tags: utility-theory

In microeconomy this theorem states that : given a consumption set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$,  if the preference relation $\succcurlyeq$ is complete, transitive and continuous there exist a utility function $u$ and it is continuous.
I've no problem at all in the first part, but at the end, to prove the continuity of $u$ it is said that it suffices to show that $u^{-1}(a,b)$ is open for all $a$,$b \in\mathbb{R}$. Well i don't get this part, is there somebody who can help me?

Comment: Where did you find this proof?

Comment: My teacher told this during lesson

Comment: This is Proposition 3.C.1 in Mas-Colell et al. "Microeconomic Theory", which also contains the corresponding proof.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about economics and not quant finance.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind questions about mathematical economics. Our user base seems to be well-suited for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f: X \to Y$ is continuous if for every open set $V$ in $Y$, the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Any open subset of the reals, which is not the empty set, is an open interval or the union of open intervals. Note that $f^{-1}(A\cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$. Since the union of open sets is open, it suffices to only consider the preimage of an open interval to prove continuity of $u : X \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: note that an open interval itself is also a union of open intervals :)